# Controlling the location where a Postgres instance will look for extension `.control` files

Tags: postgresql

Before I set off to convert some of the PostgreSQL code that I share between projects from migrations into extensions proper, I somehow become convinced that it was feasible to set up the path where Postgres will look for extension `.control` files *per cluster*. However, I am now afraid that, during my pre-takeoff checks, I might have confused [`dynamic_libray_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DYNAMIC-LIBRARY-PATH) with `SHAREDIR` (retrievable via [`pg_config --sharedir`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgconfig.html)).

I was counting on (something like) `dynamic_library_path` also working for extensions, because without a path that I can add custom locations to:

1. it's a bit difficult to install extensions at all from a CI deployment, because it requires a more complicated permission setup; and
2. and rolling out experimental extension changes on the same server becomes tricky to impossible if all my `postgres` clusters/processes have to share the same `SHAREDIR`.

To recap what I do know so far (to keep people from just copying back the official docs to me):

- `dynamic_libray_path` *can* contain a `$libdir` entry, which refers to `pg_config --pkglibdir`, but can also contain custom entries.
- However, the documentation [mentions the `dynamic_libray_path` GUC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DYNAMIC-LIBRARY-PATH) only in the context of “dynamically loadable module[s]”.
- Unlike `CREATE FUNCTION` and `LOAD`, `CREATE EXTENSION` doesn't allow one to specify a path, neither absolute nor relative.
- The [`CREATE EXTENSION` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createextension.html) plainly states that:

  > PostgreSQL will create the extension using details from the file `SHAREDIR/extension/extension_name.control`.
- [Section 38.17.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/extend-extensions.html#id-1.8.3.20.11) of the documentation mirrors this:

  > [The] control file for each extension […] must be placed in the installation's `SHAREDIR/extension` directory.
- *Within* the extension `.control` file, `directory` *can* be set so that the extension's `.sql` files *are* retrieved from another location. (The default is the aforementioned `SHAREDIR/extension`.)
- I encountered a 2020 mailing list message by Craig Ringer: [“RFC: `extension_search_path` to supplement `dynamic_library_path`”](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAGRY4nyHd4aVL_T=-FRzofLVwxHX06bqz4hb_GbzBafp9XR0NA@mail.gmail.com), which also suggest to me that, at least at the time, no such custom path mechanism existed for extensions.

  - Sadly, there do not appear to be any follow-ups to that message.

I wouldn't mind having to start `postgres` with some custom environment variable similar to `$PGDATA` even if this means that I have to bypass the OS's excellent default cluster configuration and `systemd` structure.

If it turns out that I really *cannot* control the extension file location *per `postgres` cluster*, I will probably try to use something like [`mergerfs`](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs) to overlay the files from the deployed extension directories onto `"$(pg_config --sharedir)/extension"` so that the package manager can continue to write system-wide extensions to the “lower”, original `SHAREDIR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the documentation tells you, extension control files have to be in `$(pg_config --sharedir)/extension`, and there is no way to configure a different location.